# Linking two `.bc` modules using `llvm-link` - how to remove warning?

Tags: llvm

I am linking two `.bc` modules using `llvm-as` tool.  I get always following warning:
`llvm-link module1.bc module2.bc -o module3.bc`

```
`WARNING: Linking two modules of different data layouts: './module2' is '' whereas 'llvm-link' is 'e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128'`
```

I don't understand this warning.
How to resolve/suppress it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a proper datalayout to the modules: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout

You can just re-use the one that is given in the warning message.

Comment: I dont understand you answer.  You can just re-use - how to do it ?

Comment: You likely left out the datalayout empty (default) in module2.bc, you can add it by disassemble it: `llvm-dis module2.bc` ; then edit module2.ll and add `target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"` at the beginning ; and reassemble `llvm-as module2.ll`